# NotifyChange dependent on messageBox click ZK

Tags: java, mvvm, zk

I have a template in a grid displaying a list of users. In that template is a button that lets the user be removed from the list. When the user clicks on this button I have a messageBox appear that asks them if they are sure they want to proceed. If "OK" is pressed then the user is removed. I want the list to update so that the user is no longer displayed, but it seems that @NotifyChange is doing nothing. How can I notify the template that the users list has been changed?

Here is the relevant part of the zul:

```
<grid apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer" sclass="noborder" style="padding: 5px;border:none;background-image:none"
viewModel="@id('usersVM') @init('projectName.viewmodel.ListUsersViewModel')"
model="@load(usersVM.users)"
emptyMessage="No users to display">
  <template name="model">
    <row>
        <window>
            <vlayout>
                <hlayout>
                    <label value="@load(each.fullname)" sclass="f" />
                </hlayout>
            </vlayout>     
         </window>
         <button hflex="min" label="Inactivate user" onClick="@command('inactivateUser', user=each)"/>
    </row>
  </template>
</grid>
```

Here is the relevant part of the view model:

```
List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
@Command("inactivateUser")
@NotifyChange("users")
public void inactivateUser(@BindingParam("user")
final User user)
{
    EventListener clickedOK = new EventListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(final Event e)
        {
            if (Messagebox.ON_OK.equals(e.getName()))
            {
                // remove from users so that they no longer display on this page.
                users.remove(user);
            }
        }
    };

    Messagebox.show("Are you sure you want to inactivate this user?",
            "Message from webpage", Messagebox.OK | Messagebox.CANCEL, Messagebox.NONE,
            clickedOK);

}
```

Note that the variable `users` is the List of users being displayed by the zul. I have tried adding `@NotifyChange` to the nested EventListener because I realized control leaves the `inactivateUser` function before the EventListener is activated, but it did not seem to update the list. I also have tried having the EventListener call a seperate `removeUser(User user)` function but that also did not notify changes. 
Thanks for reading.

Comment: If you set a break point at the line where the EventListener is created and another at the lin where the remove is performed in the onEvent they are two separate requests and in my jetty server than ran in two different threads. So the delete does not work in the second thread as the spring/jpa code won't work under those circumstances. Interesting...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [zk bind project site](http://code.google.com/p/zkbind/), you can download an example called **A order CRUD example v3** which demonstrates how to do this.

From the sample below, you can see that the delete button in the message box triggers a **deleteOrder** command:

```
    <window title="Confirm" mode="modal" border="normal" width="300px" visible="@load(not empty vm.deleteMessage)">
    <vbox hflex="true">
        <hlayout height="50px">
            <image src="~./zul/img/msgbox/question-btn.png"/>
            <label value="@load(vm.deleteMessage)"/>
        </hlayout>
        <hbox pack="center" hflex="true">
            <button label="Delete" onClick="@command('deleteOrder')"/>
            <button label="Cancel" onClick="@command('cancelDelete')"/>
        </hbox>
    </vbox>
</window>
```